# How to add a new menu item on OneDrive action menu?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, onedrive, office365-apps

I want to create an application which adds a new menu item to OneDrive's action menu. When my own menu item is clicked, my own application logic will be triggered.

[image]

How can I add a new menu item here? Frankly, I took a look at the Microsoft documentation, but I couldn't find where to start. I was a little confused. Which type of addin I need to create? Can you suggest me a tutorial on this subject?

Comment: Where did you get the indication that this is even possible? I have never seen or heard anything about such an option being available (Microsoft 365 at enterprise level was my core business before retirement).

Comment: I have seen this product which makes me think that it's possible

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-ca/product/web-apps/e-share.eshare-action-menu?tab=Overview